# Extract All Comments from PowerPoint File into a Text file

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a monthly PowerPoint reports that I create with relevant notes in the PowerPoint notes section. I would like to just extract these notes from the PowerPoint files over the years. Is there a VBA macro that can do this?

I know that I can create a Notes page view, but I do not really need the slide info, just the comments, preferably in the following format.

A For Loop that can take care of all the PPTX files in given folder and creates a corresponding txt file for each of those files.

> filename: Original pptx filename.txt
>
> content:
> slide 1:
>
> slide 2: Comments....
>
> Slide 3:
>
> Slide 4: Comments....

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866277/how-do-i-export-powerpoint-slide-notes-to-individual-text-files)

Comment: Let's start by clarifying whether you want comment text or notes text. In PPTspeak, they're two different things. Note text is the text that appears beneath each slide in Normal view. If notes text is what you're after, one of the routines on the link above from @cybernetic.nomad should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Steve, I mean Notes text. These are Speaker's notes.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, thank you. I am checking it out.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, that is precisely what I am looking for (I see your reply there). Can you please help with putting that code in such a way that it would work with all pptx file in given folder? With existing code, it extracts one file at a time. Really Really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look here, also on the same PPTFAQ site:  https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00536_Batch-_Do_something_to_every_file_in_a_folder.htm